# What's the cheapest method to send a large package from New Zealand?

Tags: budget, new-zealand, mail, shipping

After few months in New Zealand we are soon flying to Thailand. During our time here we picked up some gear that we would love to keep, but don't want to carry with us to Thailand.

When we asked at a local post office they said they only do air mail shipments which are expensive (~$20 per kg if I remember right).

Are there other options to send 10-15kg package to Israel from New Zealand?

Answer (score 5):

They should offer a surface mail option which is usually a lot cheaper but also a lot slower, usually around 3 months delivery time.

There are some more details on the [New Zealand Post website](http://www.nzpost.co.nz/sending-internationally/parcels/international-economy).

Comment: I've asked them and they no longer have surface option. If you check the link you given you will see that international economy is just slower airmail. It costs ~18NZD/kg and this is the option I already mentioned in my question...

Comment: I suspected this. Australia also ceased to offer surface mail some years ago. I always advise travellers not to send boxes of stuff back home ever because it's shockingly expensive. Take it with you when you go, find somebody else who can take some of it, leave it behind, pay exorbitant amounts seem to be the only options in the modern era.

Comment: Really? Sea Mail is still listed as on option on the [Australia Post website](http://auspost.com.au/internationalpost/tasks/send_parcel/economically/index.html).